# Hi Res Images, iPhone 5 vs iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I am working on an app that is more like a photogallery, where user have high res images and will be zooming and inspecting every aspect of the image. I don't have a technical question but rather asking for advice about this issue:

all images are formatted in 640 X 960 format, which works fine for retina device, except for iPhone 5. which is 640 x 1156. I can have the imageview expand but that would stretch the image and make it look elongated.
If anyone has come across this issue, what did they do? I would rather not add any extra controls to compensate for the extra space If I decide to stick with 640 X 960 on the iPhone 5 ( there's about 88 pixels of height to work with ).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you have to compensate for the iPhone/iPod 5 in that manner? If you're using UI constraints it will work itself out with the UIImageView and give you black bars at the top/bottom of the screen (assuming your background is black and the image is centered). It may also help to post what you're trying.

Comment: well I am not using constraints (too many assumptions on my behalf ). I do think a black bar top and bottom would be better and I think thats a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the contentmode property of `UIImageView`.  You would probably not want to use Scale to Fill, but there are options that preserve the aspect ratio such as aspect fit and fill.  Given the image size, this will result in clipping, but might be your best option given what you are describing.